# Retrieve value for n days prior to each date

Tags: sas

I have a dataset as follows and I need to retrieve two things: 1) the sum of VALUE between (date-1) and (date-3) for each date and 2) whether, during the 5 days, there are >= two days where the VALUE is 0. I think PROC SQL should be used but I'm not sure how to implement this. 
INPUT DATASET:

```
ID   DATE      VALUE
1   20110101     0
1   20110102     0
1   20110103     1
1   20110104     2
2   20110101     1
2   20110102     2
2   20110103     3
2   20110104     4
```

Output should be 1) 1 (0+0+1)  for ID1, 20110104 and 6 (1+2+3) for ID2, 20110104. and 2) a mark for ID1, 20110104, since there are 2 days with a value of 0 during the 3-day window.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems can be solved with a similar SQL query. Your second question is a bit confusing, because you once mention a 5 day periode and once a 3 day window. I used the same 3 day window for both queries, so modify the start and end date if you need another window.

1)

```
proc sql;
 select t1.id, t1.date, sum(t2.value) as totalvalue
 from _input t1
 left join _input t2
 on t1.date-4 lt t2.date
 and t1.date gt t2.date
 and t1.id = t2.id
 group by t1.id, t1.date;
quit;
```

2)

```
proc sql;
 select t1.id, t1.date
 from _input t1
 left join _input t2
 on t1.date-4 lt t2.date
 and t1.date gt t2.date
 and t1.id = t2.id
 and t2.value = 0
 group by t1.id, t1.date
 having count(*) ge 2
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way that just uses a data step. I'm assuming that you don't want sums and marks for ranges of less than three records so the data step explicitly sets them to undefined.

```
proc sort data=sample;
    by id date;
run;

data result(drop=k count);
    retain count;
    set sample;
    by id;

    if first.id then count=0;
    sum=lag1(value) + lag2(value) + lag3(value);
    if count<3 then sum=.;

    k=0;
    if lag1(value)=0 then k=k+1;
    if lag2(value)=0 then k=k+1;
    if lag3(value)=0 then k=k+1;
    if k ge 2 then mark=1;

    count=count+1;

run;

proc print data=result;
run;
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the lag function myself.  I find it too risky to use as it very difficult to troubleshoot bugs (eg. if you accidentally use it within an if statement).  Personally I stick to using the retain statement and doing it manually.  I find that much easier to troubleshoot.